# How do you find the path from where a cli is called from?

Tags: shell, macos

Let's say I'm building a CLI app. Let's say it's written in Python. For simplicity's sake, let's say this app echoes the given dir or file canonical path.

The user calls `myApp .`.

How can my app know where it is being called from? Does the shell provide some sort of information? An environment variable?

Expanding dot doesn't seem to work (`echo ${.}`). So the dot in of itself as a parameter is of no help. It just tells me "current dir". But, again, where do I get the current dir from?

Comment: removing all the tags that this question is specifically *not* about – you're executing python, which means you're *not* executing shell script code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Get the current working directory" is a functionality of most operating systems that have a concept of directories, and especially of these covered by this platform! It's the `getcwd()` interface offered by POSIX.

You can research how to do that on your language of choice yourself ("get current working directory with Python"), but in your case, the built-in `os` module has the functionality needed:

```
os.getcwd()
```

Answer (score 2):

The term you are missing is "(current) working directory".

In Python, you can get it via `os.getcwd()`, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html.

On most shells (without Python), you can get it via `pwd`.